# TreeMultimap in Google Collections

Tags: java, guava

Has anybody used [TreeMultimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) in Google Collections? I understand that with a TreeMultimap, its keys and values are ordered by their natural ordering or by supplied comparators. I was wondering if there is a function that allows user to supply a key and returns all the values whose keys are greater than the user-supplied key. This can be done with a SortedMap in Java which has a function called tailMap. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't used the TreeMultiMap class but a quick look at the Javadoc would suggest that you could use the [asMap()](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html#asMap()) method to get a SortedMap and then call tailMap() on that.

Comment: I haven't used TreeMultiMap either, but this certainly looks like the correct solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I made TreeMultimap.asMap() return a SortedMap to support cases like this.

Remember that tailMap() returns all entries whose keys are greater than or equal to the provided key. The original question said just "greater than".

Comment: It doesn't get more authoritative than an answer from the author.